# bidirectional one-to-one relationship (mappedBy)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

> You create a **bidirectional one-to-one relationship** using fields on
>   both classes, with an annotation on the child class's field to declare
>   that the fields represent a bidirectional relationship. The field of
>   the child class must have a @Persistent annotation with the argument
>   mappedBy = "...", where the value is the name of the field on the
>   parent class. If the field on one object is populated, then the
>   corresponding reference field on the other object is populated
>   automatically.

What can a **bidirectional one-to-one relationship** do?

Can someone give me a example?

And why I always got this error.

> Class "com.example.datastore.Employee" has field "contactInfo" with
>   "mapped-by" specified as "contactInfo". This field doesnt exist in the
>   target of the relation ("com.example.datastore.ContactInfo")!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First the Error** 
 What the error is saying is that `contactInfo` is not a field of class `com.example.datastore.ContactInfo` . They field mapped by must be a field\property of the class you are mapping to .
 
**Second The concept of Bi-Direction Mapping**
 
It's just that two tables in one-to-one or one-to-many relationship where both entities will have knowledge of the other s. You do not always need it and that depends on situation and context but generally is more common to have bi-directional one to many than one to one.
You question is about one-to-one so to give you an example of when both entities need to know about each other from Hibernate docs *A bidirectional one-to-one association on a join table is possible, but extremely unusual.*  But if you really wanted to be able to get either entiy from which ever table (which is very rare) then you create bi-directional one to one

Person and Address just to quote an example

Comment: So, can i say that a bidirectional relationship is designed to let the child object to get parent object?

Comment: In java world answer Yes as long as you are cascading the transactions (which is an easy thing and I recommend doing some reading on it) in SQL world i.e is you are not using java but just running SQL directly then it would depend on database contraints. But since you are using Java with out confusing you Answer is yes but you need to setup Cascading level a common one is DeleteOrphan which deletes child is parent is deleted but you can avoid that say you want to keep the address for a future employee then you can control and stop child from deletion

Comment: Yes you can say that a bidirectional relationship is designed to let the child object(s) to get parent object . As you dive deeper you will see that mappings refer to these relationships more as Owner side and Owned instead of Parent child .

Comment: afaik, parent-child/owner-owned is only cases that suitable to use bidirectional relationships, but it is not all.  For example, in a online shopping application, for User and Order, they are not really owner-owned relationship but they are still (kind of) suitable to have bidirectional relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer from what I learnt from Hibernate/JPA (which I think is similar)

Seems that your ContactInfo do not have relationship to Employee. To use what you described as an example for bidirectional one-to-one relationship, you will see something like (it is probably not syntactically correct, just to give u idea):

```
public class Employee {
  //... other relationship or fields

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")  // the field in ContactInfo
  private ContactInfo contactInfo;

}

public class ContactInfo {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn("EMP")
  private Employee employee;
}
```

The 'real' relationship in persistence layer is in fact dominated by ContactInfo.employee.  Setting Employee.contactInfo will not cause persistence layer to contain correct data.

I wish this help and applies to JDO too.  :P

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a one-to-one of Employee to ContactInfo. An employee has exactly one contact info, and a contact info belongs to exactly one employee. That's a bidirectional one-to-one. Your error is occurring because "mapped-by" needs to specify the name of the property of the other object that refers back to this one. For example, if you have

```
class Employee {
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;
}

class ContactInfo {
    private Employee employee;
}
```

then when you map the Employee.contactInfo property, its "mapped-by" would be "employee" because that's the property that it's "mapped by" in the ContactInfo.